# C++ "invalid initialization of non-const reference" error

Tags: c++, reference, constructor, pass-by-reference

I have two different versions of the constructor for my "Policy" class.  I can't seem to pass a Policy object by reference when using one of the constructors, and I don't understand why not.

**Overloaded constructors:**

```
Policy::Policy(int testing) { 
    initAge=160;    
    initState=1;    

    reset();        

    x[0]=4;
    x[1]=2;
    ub[0]=10;
    ub[1]=10;
    lb[0]=0;
    lb[1]=0;

}

Policy::Policy() {
    initAge=160;
    initState=1;

    reset();    

    x[FRQ]=4;
    x[BEG]=40*4;
    x[END]=75*4;
    for(int i=0; i<240; i++)
        x[2+i]=4.0;
    x[GS]=2;

    lb[0]=1;
    ub[0]=80;
    for(int i=1;i<3;i++) {
        lb[i]=160;
        ub[i]=400;
    }
    for(int i=3;i<243;i++) {
        lb[i]=1;
        ub[i]=16;
    }
    lb[243]=2;
    ub[243]=4;

}
```

**Here's my code that gives the error.**

```
void sampleMIXD(Constraints& space, Policy& p);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

//  Policy policy(1); // Works
    Policy policy(); // Does not work

    Constraints space(2);

    sampleMIXD(space, policy);

    return 0;
}
```

**Error message:**

```
'../main.cpp:64: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Policy' from a temporary of type 'Policy (*)()'
../MIXD.h:12: error: in passing argument 2 of 'void sampleMIXD(Constraints&, Policy&)'
```

If instead of `Policy policy();` I compile with `Policy policy(1);`, then the compiler doesn't complain. Please help! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Policy policy(); // Does not work
```

That's the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Try

```
Policy policy;
```

Basically, the compiler treats your variant as a declaration of a function taking nothing and returning policy. It's similar to

```
int rand();
```

Comment: Ah-hah, yes, of course!  I should have known that.  But I didn't.  Thanks.

Comment: The "most vexing parse" usually refers to something like `Policy policy(Policy());`.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Okay, so that's the second most vexing parse. The ambiguity is basically the same.

Comment: Personally, I think that `A a();` is a lot less "vexing" than `A a(A());` which, to me, is a lot less obvious,

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Then we have a sequence of more and more vexing parses `A a();`, `A a(A());`, `A a(A(A()));` etc. In this case, there can be no "most vexing" parse...

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the `()` after the `policy` variable declaration.  The compiler thinks this is a function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the error output, `Policy policy()` creates a function, which you then try to send to `sampleMIXD`. Construct it with `Policy policy;` instead (That is, omit the `()`).